# Upload file to my application on host by using servlet

Tags: servlets, file-upload, image-upload

**I have a serlvet to upload file ... It work on my server, i upload to "`http://localhost:8084/TestAmazon`" and it work ... but we deploy my web application to host and upload file it not work ... please help me**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
           String relativeWebPath = "/image";
    String absoluteFilePath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        try {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
            for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    item.write(new File(absoluteFilePath + File.separator + name));
                }
            }
            request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + e);

        }
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("message",
                "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

**i got an error:**

```
    exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Ljava/util/List;
    sample.ProcessServlet.doPost(ProcessServlet.java:73)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: Do you control the tomcat server on your host?

Comment: yes, i do. i use a free host "openshift"

Comment: Make sure the Tomcat server is using the same `servlet-api` version as your application.

Comment: Can you help me how to get servlet-api and change it. Is it in pom.xml?? Where pom.xml?

Comment: The `servlet-api` is usually provided by the Servlet container. In your pom.xml you should declare an entry for the same version of the `servlet-api` but set its `<scope>` to `provided` so that it is only used for compilation, but not for deployment.

Comment: where is pom.xml located?